# F# ToString() %A formatting doesnt work on linux with mono

Tags: linux, f#, mono

I use the fsharpc compiler installed with mono.
And I wanted to override the ToString() method for some of my types.
The thing is it all compiles just fine but `printf "%A"` just gives me the default debug output. So to make absolutly sure i didnt miss something, I wrote a simple test on try.fsharp.org and compiled the same code myself. Still just getting default formatting

So is there something missing from the .net framework or something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure that `printf` calls `ToString()`, use `%O` format instead of `%A`:

```ml
type MyType =
    {
        MyValue : string
    }
    override __.ToString() = "Hello!"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =  
    let record = { MyValue = "A value" }
    printfn "%A" record   // { MyValue = "A value" }
    printfn "%O" record   // Hello!
    0
```

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/plaintext-formatting#format-specifiers-for-printf) for details.